# Как получить get_the_date в таком формате?

Tags: wordpress

использую функцию get_the_date внутри цикла вывода постов WP. Как вывести дату в формате
***19 августа 2019***
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат вывода `get_the_date()` можно регулировать в админке сайта. Зайти на страницу `Настройки->общее раздел Формат даты` и вписать в произвольное поле нужный формат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный список параметров можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте как то так:

```
$today = get_the_date("j F, Y, g:i a");  // 10 March, 2019, 5:16 pm
$today = get_the_date("j F, Y");  //10 March, 2019
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое